# Как очистить get?

Tags: php

Как сделать кнопку назад, чтобы возвращаться ко всем записям? Я так понимаю, нужно создать функцию, которая будет очищать `$_GET['id']`

```
$query = "SELECT * FROM products";
if(isset($_GET["id"])){
    $query .= " WHERE id=?";
    $stmt = $link->prepare($query);
    $stmt->bind_param('i', $_GET["id"]);
}
else{
    $stmt = $link->prepare($query);
}

$stmt->execute();
$result = $stmt->get_result();
$row = $result->fetch_assoc();

echo '<table>
    <tr>
        <th>ID</th>
        <th>title</th>
        <th>price</th>
        <th>description</th>
        <th>category</th>
        <th>image</th>
        <th>Publish by</th>
    </tr>';
foreach($result as $item){
    echo '<tr><td>' . $item['id'] . '</td><td>' . $item['title'] . '</td><td>' . $item['price'] . '</td><td>' . $item['description'] . '</td><td>' . $item['category'] . '</td><td>' . $item['image'] . '</td>';
    if($item['active']){
         echo'<td> Да </td>';
    }
    else{
        echo '<td> Нет </td>';
    }
    if(!isset($_GET['id'])){
    echo '<td><a href="?id='. $item['id']. '">Открыть запись</a><td></tr>';
    }
    

}
```

Comment: сделайте адрес перехода по ссылке не `url?id=1`, а просто `url`

Comment: $_GET = null, не работает?